# Is there any way my Android can make himself more "robotic"?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Basically, I have an Android who wants to go about that whole Pinnochio story, but in reverse. He wants to embrace his artificial side and build himself up as a construct. Is there any way to modify himself physically to do this? IE, robotics instead of skin, mechanized body parts, etc. He just wants to shed his skin, quite literally, so become a robot.

Comment: Is this using all Paizo official material? What about 3rd party? Are you a player in a home game? How much, if at all, have you talked with your GM about this?

Answer (score 6):

### Yes, using the technology guide

Androids are native from Numeria, where a spaceship has landed into Golarion and bought lots of alien technology to that region. There is an official campaign set in Numeria: Iron Gods. That said, the [Technology Guide Campaign Setting](https://paizo.com/products/btpy98i0) book expands on the flavor and rules from that hightech part of the setting and rules and introduces dozens of new technological equiipment, including [Cybertech](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/cybertech/).

Those are implants that replace your organs and/or limbs by technological replacements, from drone eyes, to metal-hardened skin, to full arm and legs replacements. Those items are expensive and balanced just like magic items, using up slots on the character's body. So, instead of a pair of magical boots, the character could replace his legs with a cyber replacement.

Take a look on those rules, they will fit on his idea just perfectly.